# Execute function which resets vote cookie at midnight

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a site where at some point people can vote yes or no, they may only do this once a day. I found a script online that allows the user to vote only once, it has a button to reset the cookies so the user can vote again. I want the votes, function of the button, to reset after midnight. Here is the javascript code the button in html activates. It's abou the .ld-btn-reset part, that does the resetting, so I want that part to be activated at midnight.

```
    run : function()
{
    var s = '';
    s += "<div class='ld-bar-like'></div>";
    s += "<div class='ld-bar-dislike'></div>";
    s += "<div class='ld-clear-both'></div>";
    $( this.domobj ).find( '.ld-stats-bar' ).html( s );

    var _this = this;

    $( this.domobj ).find( '.ld-btn-like' ).click( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        _this.vote( $(this), 'likes' );
    });

    $( this.domobj ).find( '.ld-btn-dislike' ).click( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        _this.vote( $(this), 'dislikes' );
    });


    $( this.domobj ).find( '.ld-btn-reset' ).click( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var key = _this.getCookieName();
        Cookie.del( key );
        alert( 'Cookie has been reset!' );
    });

    this.send( '' );
},
```

Comment: When you create the cookie, set its expiration date to the next midnight.

Comment: The person could just clear their cookies. This should be done server side with ip, maybe

Comment: @bfavaretto    date.setTime( date.getTime() + ( days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ) );
  var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();

  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/"; Where should I do this? I know how to make it reset after a certain time but not at certain time.

Comment: You'd probably have to calculate how long until midnight. But @Anthony is right, you should control votes on the server, using a database or some other sort of server-side storage.

Comment: The votes are not of any value. There is no reason for some1 to cheat. So if they want I dont care

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about people "cheating the system" by clearing their cookies, then you should control the expiration date of the cookie when you set it, rather than trying to reset it.

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var expirationDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate()+1, 0, 0, 0);
$.cookie("vote", "5", {expires: expirationDate});
```

This will take the current day, add 1 day to it, and set the date to 0:00

To quote your example code in the comment below, you would use the following:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var expirationDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate()+1, 0, 0, 0);
var expires = "; expires=" + expirationDate.toGMTString(); 
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
```

To explain in a little more detail the process flow:

1. We set "currentDate" to the current time and date
2. We set a new expiration date by building a date from the current year, month and day, then we add 1 to it (to make it midnight tomorrow morning)
3. We set the "expires" string to "; expires=" and then the expiration date converted to a GMT date string
4. You then set your cookie name, value and the new expiry time

Your old code was basically adding 24 hours to the current date and time

Comment: I'm using a different plugin, so I cant use that code :/ My code looks like this: date.setTime( date.getTime() + ( days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ) ); var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString(); document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";  I need to adjust this: days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ) so it resets at midnight, no idea how..

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay - I've updated the answer to include the script in the format you'd need it